# Adequate framerate for state of the art trackers

Tags: computer-vision, tracking

I have a very simple and general question. What is ROUGHLY the actual framerate needed for today's state of the art trackers such as Kanade-Lucas Tomasi Tracker, optical flow trackers or Kalman Filtering Trackers?

I am asking this question just to get a rough idea.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how fast things move in your video. Very roughly, for tracking people and cars you want to run at about 10 fps or faster. In my experience, when the frame rate drops below 8 fps, tracking performance becomes really bad.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely dependent on the speed of appearance changes within the scene.

If the "look" of things does not change from frame to frame, you can get away with very low frame rates (e.g. you can "track" a chessboard at 0.0001 FPS, if you know there is one, regardless of the apparent position offset)

But if things start looking different from frame to frame, any tracking algorithm that assumes minor appearance changes (none, or affine), will start having problems.